# secret key on storage session does not work

Tags: express, express-session, secret-key, connect-mongo

As I understood the secret key option in connect-mongo, causes that the _id of the session inside the session store in db encrypted by the secret key and send it to client as cookie. But actually I could see the same id in the db inside the cookie (No matter what I choose as secret key). Anyone could confirm that secret key is working in connect-mongo 2.0.3?

Thanks

Comment: I also tested with the last version 3.2 and still it does not really hash the id

Comment: You should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)